# Submit form though data-val-regex errors are popped for an optional field using jquery.validate.unobtrusive

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

I have an `Asp .Net core` web application, which has few views developed using `Html5`.
I have used `jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` scripts for unobtrusive client side validation.

In one of my html page, I had few required fields and two optional fields.

```
Ex:
FirstName and LastName are required.
Zipcode and Phone number are optional.
```

Zip code must follow either `xxxxx or xxxxx-xxxx` pattern.

phone number must be exactly 10 digits.

To achieve the above, I've used `data-val-regex-pattern= [0-9]{5}(-[0-4]{4})? for Zipcode` and `data-val-length-max = 10 and data-val-length-min=10 for phone number.`

My requirement is to show the pattern error message when user input do not match the regex pattern and phone number is less than 10 digits and this error message should not stop the form submission.

But I am unable to achieve this when zipcode or phone number are not matched as per the pattern or length.

How would I submit the form though the error message is popped up especially for optional fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could validator.addMethod() and validator.addClassRules() method to add the class validate rules for the Phone Number and the Zipcode.

Sample code as below:

View page: Add a custom class for PhoneNumber and Zipcode text box.

```
@model WebApplication.Models.MyUserViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateUser";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
} 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateUser" id="myform">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" required />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" required/>
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Zipcode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Zipcode" class="form-control customzipcode" placeholder="XXXXX or XXXXX-XXXX" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Zipcode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="form-control customphone" placeholder="10 digits" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add the following Scripts at the end of above view page:

```
@section Scripts {
    @*@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}*@
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //phone number rules
        $.validator.addMethod('customphone', function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^\d{10}$/.test(value);
        }, "Please enter a valid phone number");
        $.validator.addClassRules('customphone', {
            customphone: true
        });
        //zipcode rules.
        $.validator.addMethod('customzipcode', function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]{5}(-[0-4]{4})?$/.test(value);
        }, "Please enter a valid Zipcode");
        $.validator.addClassRules('customzipcode', {
            customzipcode: true
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myform").validate(); 
        });
    </script>
}
```

The model class:

```
public class MyUserViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    public string Zipcode { get; set; } 
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

More detail information about custom validation, you could check the [JQuery validation plugins document](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).

**Update**:

> My problem is though the error message is diaplayed for optional
> fields - form submission should happen.

In the above sample, we have added the class validate rules for the Phone Number and the Zipcode. To continue submitting the form if the optional fields are invalid, in the submit button click event, you could remove the class from the optional field elements, and validate the form again, then, according to the result to submit the form. Please modify the JavaScript scripts as below:

```
<script> 
    $.validator.addMethod('customphone', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\d{10}$/.test(value);
    }, "Please enter a valid phone number");
    $.validator.addClassRules('customphone', {
        customphone: true
    });

    $.validator.addMethod('customzipcode', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]{5}(-[0-4]{4})?$/.test(value);
    }, "Please enter a valid Zipcode");
    $.validator.addClassRules('customzipcode', {
        customzipcode: true
    });
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var form = $("#myform");
        var validator = form.validate();
        $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault(); //prevent the default event.
            //remove the custom class
            $("#Zipcode").removeClass("customzipcode");
            $("#PhoneNumber").removeClass("customphone");
            if (form.valid()) {
                form.submit();
            }
            else {
                $("#Zipcode").addClass("customzipcode");
                $("#PhoneNumber").addClass("customphone");
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then, the result like this:

[image]

Comment: my problem is not to show the error messages based on pattern, I am able to achieve that.
My problem is though the error message is diaplayed for optional fields - form submission should happen.

Comment: "My problem is though the error message is diaplayed for optional fields - form submission should happen." In this scenario, the invalid value will be submit the the server side, and might be store them in the optional fields. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, I am sure... I can store invalid data for optional fields.
Could you please provide me a solution for this.

Comment: Hi @Meena, please check the update, in the submit button click event, you could remove the class from the optional field elements, and validate the form again, then, according to the result to submit the form.